# Adding days to datapicker's formatDate

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am printing date using datepicker this way:

```
$(".final-date").text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date()));
```

I am using it within my loan calculator. How can i add days to a current date? e.g. 17.01.2016, but in my calculator i choose loan period for 10 days, so it should be 27.01.2016

Comment: Will this not suffice for what you're looking for? If I've understood it correctly, you simply want to add 10 days to the current value that you have?\http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563406/add-days-to-datetime

Comment: Thanks, checking now. That's it! Post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should give you the offset date:

```
new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 1000*60*60*24*days);
```

so your code would probably become:

```
$(".final-date").text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 1000*60*60*24*10);));
```

or maybe more legibly:

```
var loanPeriodDays = 10;
var dayInMillis = 1000*60*60*24;
var loadEndDate = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + dayInMillis*loanPeriodDays);
$(".final-date").text($.datepicker.formatDate('dd.mm.yy', loadEndDate));
```